# ¿Cómo hacer un loop en numpy con vstack?

Tags: python, array, numpy

estoy trabajando en python con la libreria numpy para hacer una iteration entre dos matrices

A = prueba #Es una matriz NxN de unos y ceros
 Z = np.ones((11)) #Es una matriz fila

Estoy buscando que la multiplicación entre Z y A se itere hasta que el valor del último resultado de cero. De la siguiente manera

```
Z = Z1 * A
Z2 = Z1 * A
Z3 = Z2 * A
Zn = Zn-1 * A
```

Cada Z debe hacer un append en una matriz vacia

```
final_matrix = np.empty((0, 11), int)
```

El codigo que tengo para hacer el loop es el siguiente, sin embargo no funciona

```
> A = prueba Z = np.ones((11)) i = 0 final_matrix = np.empty((0, 11),
> int)
> 
> while i != len(Z):
>     Z = np.dot(Z, A)                      
>     np.vstack((Z, final_matrix))
>     i+=1
>     print(final_matrix)
```

Agradecería saber cuál es el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que `numpy.vstack` no actúa in-place, sino que retorna un nuevo array resultado de la concatenación. Por lo tanto, debes reasignar a `final_matrix` su salida dentro del ciclo o la llamada a `np.vstack` será totalmente inútil:

```
Z = np.ones((11))
final_matrix = np.empty((0, 11), int)

for _ in range(len(Z)):
    Z = np.dot(Z, A)
    final_matrix = np.vstack((Z, final_matrix))
    print(final_matrix)
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó. Aunque sigue operando una vez la matriz llega a cero y salen muchas filas en cero

¿Sabes cómo hacer para que una vez aparezca el primer cero se detenga?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que en Z solo existan ceros?  ¿o que contenga al menos un cero? ¿Esa z con ceros debe añadirse a final_matrix o no?

Comment: Que se detenga cuando la última fila sea son solo ceros, es que después de eso continua y continua. Intente con 

If sum(Z) ==0:
   break

Comment: `sun(Z) == 0`, `(Z == 0).all()` o `Z.sum() == 0` deben funcionar. ¿Podrías agregar el contenido de `A` a tu pregunta a ver si puedo reproducir lo que ocurre?

Comment: Ya pude amigo, gracias. por alguna razón si lo imprimo por fuera del While me sale la matriz terminando en la fila de ceros, si lo imprimo por dentro no, la corta jaja. Muchas gracias